Is it true that |X| vanishes at infinity, then X is integrable?
Suppose $X$ is a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$. If there exists $M>0$, such that for all $\lambda>0$, we have $\mathbb{P}[|X|>\lambda]\le\frac{M}{\lambda}$, then is it true that $X$ is integrable?
This condition is weaker than the absolute continuty: Does absolute continuity of integral imply integrability on finite measure space, but compared to absolute continuity, the condition above gives a explicit inequality. So, I'm not sure if it is true.
My attempt:$$\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X|>\lambda) \ d\lambda\le M\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda}\ d\lambda,$$ but the right side is infinite.

The link does not work.

Consider $X$ with density $f(t) = c/t^2$ for $t > 1$ and zero otherwise.

The condition you mention is what it means for a function (random variable) to be in weak $L^1$, which as others have mentioned, is a weaker condition than being in $L^1$

No.  A counterexample is the Cauchy distribution .  Say the random variable has density
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\,\frac{1}{x^2+1} .
$$
Then, for any set $E$ we have $\mathbb P[X \in E] = \int_E p(x)\,dx$.  So, in particular
$$
\mathbb P[|X|>\lambda] = 
\int_{-\infty}^{-\lambda} p(x)\,dx + \int_\lambda^{+\infty} p(x)\;dx
= 1 - \frac{2\arctan(\lambda)}{\pi}
$$
and this satisfies
$$
\mathbb P[|X|>\lambda] < \frac{1}{2\pi\lambda}.
$$
But also
$$
\mathbb E[|X|] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|x|p(x)\;dx = 
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\,\frac{|x|}{x^2+1}\;dx =+\infty.
$$

Terminology ...
If $\mathbb E[|X|] < \infty$ we say $X$ is in $L^1$.
If $\sup_{\lambda > 0} \lambda \mathbb P[|X|>\lambda] < \infty$ we say $X$ is in "weak $L^1$".
The counterexample shows they are not the same.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}xP(|X|>x)=0 \Leftrightarrow X \in L_1 ,$$  which was mentioned in my answer. A related question.  Is "weak $L^1$" a linear space?

The given relation $$
L^1 \subset \mathrm{weak}L^1 \subset \bigcap_{p>1} L^p
$$ needs to be corrected as $$
L^\infty \subseteq \bigcap_{p>1} L^p \subseteq L^1 \subseteq \mathrm{weak}L^1.$$
The order needs to be modified, and $\subset$ is replaced with $\subseteq$ since there are probability spaces for which all the sets are equal.

Thanks for the correction.

No. Counter-example: Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, where $\Omega=(0,1)$,
$\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{B}((0,1))$ (Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $(0,1)$)
and $P=$Lebesgue measure restricted on $(0,1)$.
Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be defined by $X(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.
For any $\lambda>1$, we have that $\{x\in\Omega\mid|X(x)|>\lambda\}=(0,\frac{1}{\lambda})$.
Hence, $P\left([|X|>\lambda]\right)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$. However,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E[|X|] & = & \int|X(x)|\,dP(x)\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx\\
 & = & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}

A counterexmple is for any $a\in (0,1]$:
$$F(\lambda)=1- \frac{1}{\lambda^{a}}, \lambda>1,$$
related to power laws.
However, note that we have the following somehow realted result that connects the asymptotic growth of tail probability and expectation as follows [2]:

$\lim_{x\to\infty}xP(|X|>x)=0$ if and only if $\mathbb E(|X|)$ is finite.

